# Help with JS return statement

Tags: javascript, tabs

this is probably an easy one, but I am new to JavaScript.

When I click on a tab which has a special id, I want that id saved in a variable. So far, so good. But if I click on a other button I want that button to work with that previous id oft he tab. How am I using the return statement correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: Store the result returned by the first function in a variable, then pass it as a parameter to the new function?

Comment: function tabsOpen(x) {
 var tab = x;
 return tab;
} 

function printTab(x) {
 tabOpen = tabsOpen(x);
 alert(tabOpen);
}

Answer (score 0):

```
// 0 = no tab 
var myTabID = 0

function doNewTab(newTabID)
{
   // If the tab has not been set
   if(myTabID <> 0){
        // Do whatever you want with the tab ID in here
        alert(myTabID);
   }

   // Set new tab ID
   myTabID = newTabID;
}
```

Then in your HTML:

```
<a onclick="doNewTab(1)" href="#">Tab1</a><br />
<a onclick="doNewTab(2)" href="#">Tab2</a><br />
<a onclick="doNewTab(3)" href="#">Tab3</a><br />
```

Comment: `if(myTabID)` should be enough

Answer (score 0):

```
var tabId = 0

function buttonClick(obj) {
  tabId = obj.id
}

<button onclick="buttonClick(this)">Button</button>
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, this.id isn't referencing anything seemingly?  Do you mean to pass this into the function?

Comment: thought `this` always referring to the object the event came from. Anyway fixed it now. This works for sure.

Comment: Mark, maybe it does, sorry if it is the case!